# get_the_permalink by custom post id returns empty .Which has been previously working. But now it's not working

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I have a huge permalink issue on the site. I am using the following code but it returns an empty value.

```
echo get_the_permalink($key->ID);
```

I have tried the_permalink(),the_permalink($key->ID),But none of them get worked.

on the custom post, the admin side post URL is directing correctly. But on the home page when getting custom post content, the custom post link is returned empty.

Comment: Can you please check if the $key variable is having any data or not. If not, then it won't work. Also, please provide more detail about the issue.

Comment: I have tried with $key but it also returns empty value. On  the site get permalink return empty value for all custom post . but for shop page it's okay.